# Interpolation with Regularized Linear Squares

Tags: least-squares, inverse-function, regularization, inverse-problems

I am fundamentally missing something and would appreciate some clarification. I am reading the book [Statistical Image Processing and Multidimensional Modeling](https://doi.org/10.1007/978-1-4419-7294-1) on Regularized Least Squares. This text has a problem where I have to find z, a set of unknown elements. z in this case is a column vector of five 2D points.

To compute $\hat{z}$, I use the following equation (provided by the text):

$$\hat{z} = (C^TR^{-1}C+\lambda LL^T)^{-1}C^TR^{-1}\vec{m}$$

where C is the transformation matrix, L is the constraint matrix, $\vec{m}$ is the measurement column vector and R is an Identity matrix.

$$\vec{m} = C\vec{z} + \vec{v} = \begin{bmatrix}z_{1}\\z_{5}\end{bmatrix} +\vec{v}$$

where $\vec{v}$ ~ I and $\vec{m} = \begin{bmatrix}10\\50\end{bmatrix}$

Here's the thing this problem is set on a 2D plane, so z is a vector of 2D (x,y) points. However, the text does not give m, a set of measurements on the 2D plane, in the same type. Instead m is a column vector of [10;50]. This reduces z to a column vector as well.

The question then asks us to plot z. How can I plot z if I have only a column vector?

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1):

I think you can set the vector $\vec{z}$ in the following form
\begin{equation}
\vec{z} =
\begin{pmatrix}
x_1\\
y_1\\
x_2\\
y_2\\
\vdots\\
x_n\\
y_n
\end{pmatrix},
\end{equation}
or, for example, in the following form
\begin{equation}
\vec{z}=
\begin{pmatrix}
x_1\\
x_2\\
\vdots\\
x_n\\
y_1\\
y_2\\
\vdots\\
y_n
\end{pmatrix}.
\end{equation}